# .htaccess slash in name get variable issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi and sorry for bothering you, i try to look around but i couldn't find a solution, and i really can't figure out how and if it's possible to do something like that with rewriterule.

This is the portion of htaccess file interested in my problem:

> RewriteRule ^pagename/([^/]+)-([^/]+) mypage.php?name=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]

example.com/mypage/dogarticle-800ad43

so my variable in php will be like

> $_GET["name"]=dogarticle  and $_GET["name"]=800ad43

so far so good, but if an article contain a slash i can't get the right variable anymore, example

example.com/mypage/animals/dogandcat-800ad44

where animals/dogandcat should be name i receive the following get vars:

> $_GET["name"]=animals $_GET["name"]=dogandcat

**Here the question what should i do to receive the following get var:**

> $_GET["name"]=animals/dogandcat $_GET["name"]=800ad44>

Cant really figure out the solution, probably not the best of my days.

Thanks

edit:
in the name there can be a lot of slash example:

> example.com/mypage/animals/dogandcat/squirrel/someotheranimal-800ad44

Comment: it looks like you need to clean up your url structuring out side of that you could `urlencode` your URL so that the `/` = `%2F` ie `urlencode('animals/dogandcat');` that way you are selecting the right portion of the url

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i was also thinking as last resource to do somehing like that php or js side, but i was just wondering if it wasnt possible directly with htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^pagename/(.+)-([^/]+)$ mypage.php?name=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: thanks so much really u saved me for lot of troubles, it's just perfect